# How to set the background image?

Tags: html

What would the HTML code be to set this url as my background...?

http://fin6.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/6c16724dd8d4aef072e62caeb164ff372.jpg

[image]

I am using Lead System Network.com' creation wizard trying to set a background as a landing page.

Comment: What have you tried? What were the results? Assuming you have tried googling 'HTML set background image', what problems did you encounter implementing the results? If they weren't appropriate, can you clarify your question further?

Comment: Are you aware that clicking that link (at first) redirects to a landing page (which is not an image)? Perhaps the problem you're having is that you don't have a direct link to the image because the site won't let you have one - have you tried other images to experiment?

Answer (score 0):

You could either add the background attribute to your body tag.

```
<body background="IMAGENAME.jpg">
```

Or you can add a CSS rule for the body element like

```
body {
   background-image:url('IMAGENAME.jpg');
}
```

and include the CSS in the HTML header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with css as the example of a friend or html  shape but I do not recommend it because it is obsolete. 
working with css, remember that all images you use for the web must be in the root folder of your project or it will not work.